# Spreadsheet script doesn't run if the spreadsheet is shared

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script that would copy a row from a big database and that way makes it easier to modify.

**The main point would be to allow more editor to modify the database parallel. However, if I share the spreadsheet, other users get the following error:** *Script ... experienced an error.* The user encounters this problem by scripts assigned to a button only. `onEdit()` runs just fine.

It's my first google script file, so I have really no idea that what's the problem and how should I solve it.

The whole code is here:

```
//copy the chosen row to the appropriate cells of the editor sheet
//if zero sets the cells to default
function copySelectedRow(){ 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shData=ss.getSheets()[0];
  var shEdit=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var idNumber = shEdit.getRange(1,2).getValue();

  if(idNumber == 0) {
    var arrayData = [["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]];
  } else {
    var rowNumber=findRow(idNumber);

    if(rowNumber == -1) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Nincs ilyen betegszam!');
      return;
    }

    var range1=shData.getRange(rowNumber,1,1,shData.getLastColumn());
    var arrayData=range1.getValues();
  }

  var arrayDataT = new Array(new Array);
  var arr = new Array(new Array);
  var arrT = new Array(new Array);

  arrayDataT = transpose(arrayData);

  arrT = arrayDataT.slice(1,6);
  arr = transpose(arrT);
  shEdit.getRange(5,1,1,5).setValues(arr);

  shEdit.getRange(2,4).setValue(arrayData[0][6]);

  arrT = arrayDataT.slice(7,11);
  shEdit.getRange(7,2,4).setValues(arrT);

  arrT = arrayDataT.slice(7,11);
  shEdit.getRange(7,2,4).setValues(arrT);

  shEdit.getRange(7,3).setValue(arrayData[0][11]);

  arrT = arrayDataT.slice(12,16);
  shEdit.getRange(7,4,4).setValues(arrT);

  arrT = arrayDataT.slice(16,20);
  shEdit.getRange(12,2,4).setValues(arrT);

  shEdit.getRange(12,3).setValue(arrayData[0][20]);

  arrT = arrayDataT.slice(21,25);
  shEdit.getRange(12,4,4).setValues(arrT);
}


//trasnspone a 2D array
 function transpose(a)
{
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}


//save the cells to the database, checks and writes out if the editor is sure or unsure
function saveData() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var shData = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]; 
  var shEdit = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var idNumber = shEdit.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var row = findRow(idNumber);
  if(row == -1) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Nincs ilyen betegszam!');
  return;
  }

  var arr = new Array;
  var arrT = new Array(new Array());
  var arrayData = new Array(new Array());
  var tempArray = new Array(new Array());

  arrT = shEdit.getRange(7,2,4).getValues();
  arr = transpose(arrT);
  arrayData.push(arr);

  arrT = shEdit.getRange(7,3).getValue();
  tempArray[0][0] = arrT;
  arrayData.push(tempArray);

  arrT = shEdit.getRange(7,4,4).getValues();
  arr = transpose(arrT);
  arrayData.push(arr);

  arrT = shEdit.getRange(12,2,4).getValues();
  arr = transpose(arrT);
  arrayData.push(arr);

  arrT = shEdit.getRange(12,3).getValue();
  tempArray[0][0] = arrT;
  arrayData.push(tempArray);

  arrT = shEdit.getRange(12,4,4).getValues();
  arr = transpose(arrT);
  arrayData.push(arr);

  tempArray = new Array(new Array);

  var count = 0;
  for(var i=1; i<arrayData.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<(arrayData[i][0].length); j++){
      tempArray[0][count]=arrayData[i][0][j];
      count++;
      }
  }

  shData.getRange(row,8,1,18).setValues(tempArray);


  var sure = shEdit.getRange(20,6).getValue();

  if(sure) {
  shData.getRange(row, 7).setValue("KÉSZ");
  shEdit.getRange(2,4).setValue("KÉSZ");
  } else {
  shData.getRange(row, 7).setValue("BIZONYTALAN");
  shEdit.getRange(2,4).setValue("BIZONYTALAN");
  }

}


//returns the row number of the id value in the database
function findRow(idNumber) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var shData = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]; 
  var matchArray = shData.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  for(var count=0; count<matchArray.length; count++){
      if(matchArray[count][0]==idNumber) return count+1;
  }
  return -1;
}


//runs if the id cell is modified
function onEdit(e) { 
  var range = e.range;
  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
  var rowOfCellEdited = range.getRow();

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 2 && rowOfCellEdited === 1) {
    copySelectedRow();
    collision();
  }
};


//increment the value of id by one
function incrementByOne() { 
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tempNumber = targetSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(tempNumber+1);
  copySelectedRow();
  collision();
}


//decrement the value of id by one
function decrementByOne() { 
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tempNumber = targetSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(tempNumber-1);
  copySelectedRow();
  collision();
}

//writes out if more editors are editing the same line
function collision(){ 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();

  var idArray = new Array();
  var temp;

  for(var i=1; i<allSheets.length; i++){
    temp = allSheets[i].getRange(1,2).getValue();
    idArray.push(temp);
  }

  var collisionArray = new Array();

  for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++){
    for(var j=i+1; j<idArray.length; j++){
      if(idArray[i] == idArray[j]){
        collisionArray.push(i);  
        collisionArray.push(j); 
      }
    }
  }

  for(var i=1; i<allSheets.length; i++){
    allSheets[i].getRange(1,3).setValue("");
  }

  for(var i=0; i<collisionArray.length; i++){
    allSheets[collisionArray[i]+1].getRange(1,3).setValue("SZERKESZTÉS ALATT");
  }
 }
```

So if I click the drawing that is associated with `incrementByOne`, it will give an error, but if I just change the cell, `onEdit()` can call the same functions easily.

(Sorry for the long code, I don't know which part could be important. If you tell me, I'll make it shorter.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

If I share the code with a link, an anonymous editor can not use every script, because of authentication issues (don't ask why it isn't a problem by onEdit() ). Also, if the editor logs in into his/her gmail account and accepts everything, the script will become runable (but maybe a bit slower than on the owners account).